# Rx Replay and Join

Tags: system.reactive, rx-java, rxjs

I create function, it works but i don't understand why.

Task.

There is 2 streams.

1. Notifications stream N
2. Quotes stream Q

The function should pair up Notification with Quote on following conditions:

1. When new Notification arrived to N stream, it should be paired with latest quote from Q stream.
2. If the notifications arrived before first quote arrived, them all should be paired with the first arrived quote.
3. If N stream started some time later after Q stream started, it still should  have access to the last quote from Q stream.

Marble diagrams

1.

```
--N1--N2--N3-------------
---------------Q1--------
---------------N1-N2-N3--
               Q1 Q1 Q1
```

2.

```
    -----------N1----N2--N3-----
    --Q1--Q2------Q3------------
    -----------N1----N2--N3----
               Q2    Q3  Q3
```

Now this is my function

```
//qs, ns - hot streams

var rqs = qs.replay(null, 1);

qs.connect();
rqs.connect();

ns.connect();

var cs = ns.join(rqs, 
                 _ => rqs,
                 _ => qs,
                 (n, q) => {
                    return {n : n, q : q};
                }             
).distinctUntilChanged(x => x.n);
```

https://jsbin.com/zeyiyeg/edit?js,console

And here I don't understand why

1. Why rqs always notified before qs
2. Can't grasp a logic of join in this case
   When new notification and quote arrived, join opens next window and wait till
   `_ => rqs` stream completed, why it is completed at all, rqs - is hot stream and should not be copmpleted at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the function above as follow:

`rqs` and `qs` stream never closed hot streams (which is wrong, the join params should return `completed` streams), since that each and every quote and notif will produce result to result stream, and there is will be created new stream each time when new notif arrived, and one never be closed. In other words this is wrong.

Still wonder why `rqs replay` stream receive notification before source `rs` stream, even it connected after `rs`

```
//replay latest quotes hash {"A": latestPrice, "B": latestPrice}
var rqs = qs
.scan({}, (x, v) => { x[v.t] = v; return x;})
.replay(null, 1);

qs.connect();
rqs.connect();

ns.connect();

//group by ticket
var cs = ns.groupBy(n => n.t).selectMany(x => {


  //get quotes stream for group ticket
  var gqs = rqs.where(q => q[x.key]).map(q => q[x.key]);

  //wait till first quote arrive, collect all notifs 
  var s = x.join(
    gqs.take(1), 
    _ => gqs.take(1), 
    _ => gqs.take(1),
    (n, q) => {return {n : n, q : q};}
  );

  //s.subscribe(createObserver("s:" + x.key));

 return s.concat(x.combineLatest(gqs, (n, q) => {
    return {n : n, q : q};})
 ).distinctUntilChanged(x => x.n);

});

//rqs.subscribe(createObserver("rqs"));
cs.subscribe(createObserver("cs"));
```

Bonus - quotes and notifications grouped by ticket

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. Answers should be fully articulated within Stack Overflow.